# High Frequency Udp Multicast sending : after a while java.net.SocketException

Tags: java, networking, udp, multicast, datagram

I have developed an app that sends around 4 packets per second on three different multicast UDP addresses, for a total of 12 packets per second. The packet size is small, a 50 char String. After a while (20 minutes), all threads that handle the packet dispatch launch the exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.sendFromNativeBuffer(DatagramChannelImpl.java:521)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send(DatagramChannelImpl.java:483)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send(DatagramChannelImpl.java:462)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel.doWriteMessage(NioDatagramChannel.java:293)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel.doWrite(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:142)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:939)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:906)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1370)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:739)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:731)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:739)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:731)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$2100(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1139)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1062)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:495)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The app runs on Windows 10 and JVM 1.8
I suspect the problem is related to Datagram Buffer of S.O. or of JVM. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved. The problem was related to System Operative UDP ports saturation. Modified the code properly, problem resolved.

Comment: Modified what code? Modified it how? How are this question or answer useful?

Comment: The app code that sends packets. The app opened too many TCP/IP connections, afterwards, I corrected the bug.